# Locus of a point where two circles having a common tangent meets

Tags: circles

Let *T* be the line passing through the points *P*(-2,7) and *Q*(2,-5). Let *$F_1$* be the set of all pairs of circles *$(S_1,S_2)$*, such that *T* is tangent to *$S_1$* at P and tangent to *$S_2$* at Q, and also such that *$S_1$* and  *$S_2$*  touch each other at a point, say, M. Find the locus of point M.

Actually what i presume that the distance between the centre of the circle is $4\sqrt10$ unit , it is the distance between P and Q. But not able to proceed from here onward as i am not able to formulate it.

Comment: Assuming touch means are tangent to, by experimenting in geogebra, the locus of $M$s seems to be the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=40$.

Comment: Hint: if you want to solve it algebraically you can choose a more convenient coordinate system, where $P=(-d,0)$ and $Q=(d,0)$ and from there show that the points $M$ indeed lie on a circle of radius $d$ about the origin. Knowing the answer, you can also prove it by using geometry.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland The locus you are claiming involves the point P and Q in it. If M coincides with P or Q then then the radius of one circle becomes zero which means it is a point no a circle... Also if M coincides with P or Q then it would mean that the tangent of a circle meets that circle at two points... whereas **a tangent to a circle can only meet a circle at a single point**.

Comment: @Sid  just take away those two points. Simulate the situation in something like geogebra and see for yourself.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I'm not saying you are wrong. You are right. Its just that you must exclude points P and Q from the locus... The problem is not complicated, (if you observe the question properly you will notice chords PM and QM are perpendicular giving the eqn of a circle in diametric form.)

Comment: @Sid obviously.

Comment: @amd Why making this older question the duplicate? The content in the newer post isn't necessarily better.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I tried that, but this questions has neither an upvoted nor an accepted answer, so it was rejected by MSE as an original.

Answer (score 0):

[image: circle]

Let $A=(-2+3a/\sqrt{10},7+a/\sqrt{10})$ be the center of the circle tangent to $T: -3x-y+1=0$ at $P$, it is $a$ along the normal to $T$ at $P$. And similarly $B=(2+3b/\sqrt{10},-5+b/\sqrt{10})$. Then the right triangle with hypotenuse $a+b$ and catheti $\sqrt{160}$ and $a-b$, gives the relation $(a+b)^2=160+(a-b)^2$ i.e. $b=40/a$.

The equations of the circles are $$(x-(-2+3a/\sqrt{10}))^2+(y-(7+a/\sqrt{10}))^2=a^2$$ and $$(x-(2+3\cdot 40/(a\sqrt{10}))^2+(y-(-5+40/(a\sqrt{10})))^2=(40/a)^2.$$ And the double intersection point is $$M=((2(12 a \sqrt{10}+a^2-40))/(a^2+40), (280-5a^2+8 a \sqrt{10})/(a^2+40))$$ which we can implicitize to $x^2+(y-1)^2-40=0$.

For completeness the implicitization in [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/):

```
R=QQ[a,b,c,x,y,z]
I=ideal(c^2-10,x-(2*(12*a*b*c+a^2-40*b^2)), y-(280*b^2-5*a^2+8*a*b*c),z-(a^2+40*b^2))
gens gb I
```

yields $x^2+y^2-2yz-39z^2$ which is $x^2+y^2-2y-39$ dehomogenized or $x^2+(y-1)^2-40=0$.

**Edit**

@Sid: Of course, excluding the points $P$ and $Q$ on $x^2+(y-1)^2=40$, since then one circle is reduced to a point and the other becomes the line between $P$ and $Q$, and in the limits are not circles.

Comment: i think points P and Q must be excluded from the locus right? As this would mean the tangent meets the circle S1 or S2 at two points... and **a tangent can only meet a circle at one point.**

Comment: @Sid: See edit.

Comment: I saw the edit. The only reason I took this seriously is because this was a multiple choice question and one option was: is (-2,7) is in the locus? I posted a simpler solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be the centers of the two tangent circles and $C$ the intersection of their common tangent through $M$ with $T$. Consider $\angle{PMQ}$. Both $\triangle{PCM}$ and $\triangle{QCM}$ are isosceles, so, chasing angles, $$\begin{align} m\angle{PMQ} &= m\angle{PMC}+m\angle{CMQ} \\ &= \frac12(\pi-m\angle{PCM})+\frac12(\pi-m\angle{QCM}) \\ &= \frac12(\pi-m\angle{PCM})+\frac12(m\angle{PCM}) \\ &= \frac\pi2. \end{align}$$ Recalling the theorem about right angles inscribed in a circle, this means that the locus of the points $M$ is a circle with diameter $\overline{PQ}$, less the points $P$ and $Q$ themselves.

For an analytic solution, you could use the fact that the centers $C_1$ and $C_2$ of the circles lie on the perpendiculars to $T$ through $P$ and $Q$, respectively. $P-Q=(4,-12)$, so the two centers have parameterizations $C_1 = P+\lambda(3,1)$ and $C_2 = Q+\mu(3,1)$. From the tangency condition, we have $|C_1C_2|=|C_1P|+|C_2Q|$. This, along with the fact that the two circles must be on the same side of $T$ will allow to to solve for, say, $\mu$ in terms of $\lambda$, giving you a one-parameter family of tangent circle pairs. Solve for their intersection point and eliminate $\lambda$ to get an implicit Cartesian equation for the locus of intersection points.

Answer (score 0):

The equation tangent T (passing through P & Q) : **y + 3x = 1**.

Note that P$C_{1}$ and Q$C_{2}$ are perpendicular to the tangent as: the line joining **the point of intersection of the tangent to the circle** and **the center of that circle** is always **perpendicular** to the tangent line. Also the set of all lines drawn from the center of a generic circle to a point on that circle is **equidistant**. Hence, any triangle consisting of two distinct vertices on the circle and one vertex in center of the circle is an **isosceles triangle**.

[image: Geometrical representation]

This image is just an example of two generic circles in F1. There are infinitely many more. But from this generic image we get a result: the angle between PMQ remains 90 degrees (right angle) i.e: $\frac{x+2}{y-7}$**.**$\frac{x-2}{y+5}$**=-1**.  From this, the **diametric form of a circle** comes to the mind.

Now one thing to note is that: **if a line is tangent to a circle then that line can only meet that circle at one point.** Hence points P and Q are **excluded** from the locus as that would mean the tangent touches two points of either S1 or S2 respectively. Along with this if the point M **coincides** with P or Q this makes the radius of one circle zero (a point) and the other infinity (a straight line).

**Locus is of M:  $x^2+y^2 = 2y +39$ excluding: {(-2,7),(2,-5)}**